# Wordpress | Custom editable permalink per post

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

On my website I have a page showing all portfolio items.
Every portfolio item has a link to their own detail page.

My client wants to display every portfolio item on that page (Portfolio page), but not every item needs a detail page.

Some portfolio items only have a title and a preview image.
On their current (Wordpress) website they are overwritting the permalink to '#'. (Using a plugin which I don't seem to find)

I thought about adding a checkbox to the Custom Post Type to wether use the real link or not. But this seems to be way too much work editing every post.

Does anyone know how to solve this easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to remove link from the post and use post id as class or id for identify the post.

Comment: This is so dirty, I am not going to re-write my jQuery file every single time a new portfolio item gets added...

Comment: what is the condition not to go to detail page.

Comment: Because there is no content.

Comment: then simple add the condition that if content is null or blank then there should not be link otherwise there will be a link inside the loop of portfolio.And for getting content you can use----- if($post->post_content == ' ').